# How to use watchdog timer in ATmega128

Tags: avr, atmega, timer, watchdog

I am working with an ATmega128 and need to reset the microcontroller after some 10 seconds has passed and the user has not interacted with microcontroller. As an example when the user has not pressed any key from a keypad for 10 seconds the controller should get reset.

A watchdog timer is available in the ATmega128 but I am able to get a maximum of 2 seconds delay before it resets. But I require 10 seconds.

Maybe I can do it using timers but I don't know how to proceed?

Comment: Even I tried with the Header file #include<avr/wdt.h> and used like:                      wdt_enable(WDTO_8S);                                   wdt_reset();                                           But not got any response by these functions. I am working in Linux AVR-GCC.

Comment: Do you really need the system *reset* or could you just re-start the program from the top?

Comment: For timers - here is a good tutorial: http://www.avrfreaks.net/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=viewtopic&t=50106

Comment: @JohnU: Thanks for your reply and Actually in my project I am asking user for password, if he enters wrong password it will be in that loop only until he gives right password. So what i need is if user not gave any input to the controller it should start from at top of the program.

Comment: So why not just write the program so it does that?

Comment: @JohnU: Yes i did using label and used "goto" that particular label. But what i need is when user not enters anything that time my program should wait for some 5 to 10 seconds then it should go back to top of program. Please  help with example code if possible.

Comment: The easiest thing is to use a wait() command... if that does not exist (almost all languages have one) it's easy to make one by doing something like `for(i=99999;i>0;){i--;}` which just counts down from a big number. This is generally seen as a bad way of adding delays as it stops the CPU doing anything else, but it's the most basic.

Comment: @JohnU: I got your point but when I add this delay to main program but while this wait delay i am not able read keypad right.

Comment: Another idea: Start a timer before accepting inputs from User, Reset that timer everytime user enters something... If user is inactive for given time, Timer will overflow... Set flag in timer and if that flag is set, break out from your "Accept Input" Loop!

Comment: @sanju -  what Swanand said is the right sort of idea. This is quite basic stuff, and using the watchdog is not a good way of doing it. In our system we have a 1KHz hardware timer running on an interrupt routine, this increments a "ticks" value like a clock. In our main software, if we want to reset something after 10sec we remember the "tick" value now, and when there are 10,000 *more* ticks we reset the status.

Comment: @Swanand: Yes thats good idea. I will try. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: @JohnU: Yes I will try the same.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using Watchdog timer for this purpose,

Start a timer before accepting inputs from User, Reset that timer everytime user enters something... If user is inactive for given time, Timer will overflow... Set flag in timer and if that flag is set, break out from your "Accept Input" Loop!

Comment: Also note that ten seconds is a long time, and it may not be possible to stretch the hardware timer peripheral that far, of if you can could lock up a valuable timer and not allow it to be used for anything else. Having the timer interrupt perodically, say 1 seconds or less, and decrementing some sort of countdown may be a more optimum way to go.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to achieve the same. Use the watchdog (i.e. internal or external). If its external you have to check its datasheet and response according to it. The internal watchdog must be set for 2 seconds then reset it in loop for more than 1 sec. it is favorable to use a timer for the same purpose.  Just rest the watchdog after every second and reset the watchdog counter after 5 times.